# Gson ignores serialization exclusion strategy

Tags: java, gson

Serializing

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int someProperty;

    public Subclass() {
    }

    public Subclass(int someProperty, String myProperty) {
        super(myProperty);
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }

    public int getSomeProperty() {
        return someProperty;
    }

    public void setSomeProperty(int someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
}
```

with

```
public class Superclass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String myProperty;

    public Superclass() {
    }

    public Superclass(String myProperty) {
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }

    public String getMyProperty() {
        return myProperty;
    }

    public void setMyProperty(String myProperty) {
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }
}
```

shouldn't fail because of

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class richtercloud.gson.exclusion.strategy.Subclass declares multiple JSON fields named serialVersionUID
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:661)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:583)
    at richtercloud.gson.exclusion.strategy.Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

if a serialization exclusion strategy is used as follows:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT)
        .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                boolean retValue = f.getName().equals("serialVersionUID");
                return retValue;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .create();
Subclass a = new Subclass();
String response = gson.toJson(a);
System.out.println(response);
```

I'm using Gson 2.8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Analysis

It seems, this is a known issue:

- [Integrate with java.sql.ResultSet · Issue #464 · google/gson · GitHub](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/464).
- [error happend when converting object to json · Issue #399 · google/gson · GitHub](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/399).

## Some alternative solutions

### Solution #1: Use type adapter

The recommended solution there (see the «Analysis» links), the workaround, is to introduce an appropriate type adapter.

### Solution #2: Exclude static fields from serialization

Why not exclude the serialization of the static fields at all?

```
new GsonBuilder()
    // ...
    .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC)
    // ...
```

### Solution #3: Serialize `@Exposed` fields only

It is possible to explicitly expose serializable fields by using the `@Exposed` annotation and configure the `GsonBuilder` appropriately:

```
new GsonBuilder()
    // ...
    .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
    // ...
```

Comment: Since the issues have been closed for no reason and this is still not fixed over the years or never has been formulated in a way that expresses the need for this issue to be fixed, I opened https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1236

Comment: The 3rd solution shown here is the only workaround that works for my custom type (adding excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotations to the builder).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only calling `addSerializationExclusionStrategy`, but when Gson builds the internal reflection-based adapter it considers serialization *and deserialization*. Therefore you must also use [`GsonBuilder.addDeserializationExclusionStrategy`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy)) to register the same exclusion strategy for deserialization.